# SoapUI can't open wsdl from url

Tags: java, web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have a problem:

There is wsdl
http://localhost:8080/foo/foo.wsdl

with:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:app="http://foo/equeue/ws/" 
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:smev="http://bar/123" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"  
jxb:version="2.0" targetNamespace="http://bar/123">

<xsd:import namespace="http://foo/equeue/ws/types/" schemaLocation="../types/etypes.xsd"/>
<xsd:import namespace="http:/foo/equeue/ws/" schemaLocation="../types/eapptypes.xsd"/>

<xsd:include schemaLocation="../types/123.xsd"/>
<xsd:complexType name="SomeType">
...
```

And soapUi can't open this wsdl: error is
**Error loading [http://localhost:8080/types/eapptypes.xsd]: java.io.IOException: Attempted read from closed stream**

If I use //file from hdd - and send all request to localhost:8080/foo
All works fine.

Could you help me? Why suapUI can't open localhost wsdl?

Thank you!

Comment: Check if your proxy settings are correct

Comment: All works fine with other web services...

Comment: Can you share the HTTP log at SoapUI?

Comment: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: Are the web services that work also published on localhost?

Comment: Yes, all services published on localhost

Comment: Can you access the WSDL URL in a browser?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.